# Objeto Ghost em WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que exibe uma faixa informativa em WPF C#, ja desenvolvi a mesma com o Windows Form C#, e estou querendo aplicar um, evento creio eu, que faz com que essa faixa seja uma espécie de fantasma, ou seja, ela aparece ali, mostra o efeito e tudo mais, porem quando o mouse esta por cima dele, aparece como se não estivesse ali, se tivesse um arquivo iria aparecer o formato de click no ponteiro do mouse ou com aquela mão na time line do youtube por exemplo... eu ouvi falar que esse efeito se chama Ghost, mas não achei nada sobre isso. Alguém sabe como faz isso?

Imagem da faixa
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]